# How to create an HTML code to place two boxes one above the other in Tibco Spotfire?

Tags: html, css, spotfire

I want to make a text box with this specific outlook:

[Desired Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5X6Y.png)

But I can't find resources on how to do it. Is there any help? Also in how to make the text boxes like that, which are kind of squares with text within. Especially, I have problems with changing the sizes (height and width) of these boxes. Even if I specifically mention it, it won't change

On my own, I was only able to whip out some basic HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My HTML Page</title>
    <style>
      .title {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
      }
      .object {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="object">
      <h2 class="title">Cluster</h2>
      <p><SpotfireControl id="b4969e13ff1449ebb42b49e887569e91" /></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code, pay attention to use `margin: auto`. Also you can change `height` in obj1 and obj2. for example use some another units like rem, em, % and etc...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My HTML Page</title>
    <style>
      .title {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        margin:auto;
      }
      .mainBox {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: pink;
      }
      .obj1 {
        width: 50%;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: red;
        text-align: center;
        
      }
       .obj2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainBox">
        <div class='obj1'>
            <h1 class='title'>Amir</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='obj1'>
            <div class='obj2'>
                <h1 class='title'>Amir</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='obj2'>
                <h1 class='title'>Amir</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Study some artiles and documentions like [this article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-layout/amp/) if you want to know more about layouts.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer. This seems to work, I just want to ask if its possible to like switch the title on top of the items? As it is, I modified it now and it looks like this:

Tipo Elemento: OBJECT
Direzione: OBJECT.

I kinda wanted to have the title on top. Also, is there a way to change the height of the objects directly? This program doesn't allow me to directly, maybe through HTML there is a way

Comment: Html default is at the top of the box so i will edit my solution.